# How to transfer bitcoins from one Currency to Another from Brazil

Tags: buy-bitcoins, currencies, exchange-rate

I want to send money from real BRL to euro EUR. I live in Brazil.

How can I use bitcoins for that? And How would I make the bitcoins available for the person to spend in Euros?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You both need to have bitcoin wallet and know each other BTC address.

If you both have both bank accounts in each country it makes easy.

- Buy BTC in your country with BRL.
- Send BTC to the person living anywhere in the world.
- He can convert his bitcoin against EUR via lobalbitcoins, exchanges or ATM in some cities. 
  Converting bitcoin to EUR might not be easy. Exchanges will require verification documents. If he can contact persons or go to an bitcoin ATM machine, that will probably not require verification process.

Comment: ATM? This is great @W3bit ! The only problem is that I don't have account in those countries, only in Brazil, is there any workaround?

Comment: A Bitcoin ATM does not require a bank account.